# How to see your new votes in the new user interface?

Tags: support, user-interface

[image]

As per subject: looks like there has been a recent interface change (see picture above), and now that the little mail icon has gone missing, I am totally unable to find the page that used to show new votes on your questions and answers. So, if somebody up/down-voted me, I can't know *where*.

Is that page still available? How can it be reached?

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff - I would really like to see this functionality restored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hover over the arrow or your username, and the current popup displays your recent rep changes:

[image: rep changes]

Answer (score 8):

It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/ or https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/USERNAME

Hopefully we will get it back as usual soon!

Comment: this should not be accepted in my opinion, its a great help, but it a hack, and as a programmer - I do not like hacks, we should wait for an answer from the people who organized this move.

Comment: You're such a rep thief ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Post an answer and I will upvote it. hehe

Comment: This really shouldn't be accepted: [These links may not work anymore in the future](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope/82539#82539) (comment by Nick Craver).

Comment: I agree. This hack will probably not work soon.

Comment: Hopefully voting this up will be a sign that this change should be reverted - or at least add a link to the little popup that takes you to the old page.

Comment: You people are right, answer unaccepted.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I've found something similar:

[image]

Personally, I liked ***a lot more*** the previous layout.

Comment: Click your name at the top of the page where there is a reputation link - that takes you to the page in your screenshot:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope

Comment: @Rebecca - clicking on reputation just shows me a the graph and no data despite having recent upvotes.

Comment: This is not the same as http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent

Comment: @Arjan, I did not say it was the same page.  I was just explaining how to get to the page shown in the screenshot of this answer.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope) for more details.

Comment: @ChrisF, what's the date at the bottom?  Adjust the date range?

Comment: @Rebecca - It just gives today's date (3/11/2011 12:00:00 AM) and I've *never* been able to get the graph to show just one day's worth of data.

Comment: @Rebecca - The Mail icon interface showed me all upvotes and accepts since last time I checked.  So if I come on 6 hours later and see my rep went up 50 points, I can click the mail icon and it would show me exactly what questions and answers were upvoted or accepted, nothing more, nothing less.  I miss that :(

Comment: @Rebecca, I did not use @Rebecca ;-)

Comment: its not that you would prefer the old interface is that people do not like change, but you should embrace it.

Comment: Also, you haven't been very active on SO recently have you.

Comment: @Robert: I instead *have*. And ave been for a while. And I liked the old design a lot more.

Comment: @Robert: Is this "its not that you would prefer the old interface is that people do not like change" a joke?

Comment: @Robert, SE is more than only SO.

Comment: yea but SO is the mother load ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make it something like this

[image: http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent]